# does primitive variable need to be volatile if assigned once in constructor

Tags: java, volatile

With the example below, let's say Thread A creates object X, Thread B calls method getY(), does variable y need to be declared volatile to be visible to Thread B?

```
public class X{
   int y;

   public X(){
      y=10;
   }

   public int getY(){
     return y;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does primitive variable need to be volatile if assigned once in constructor

That is one solution, but there are other solutions too.

The scenario that is likely to affect you here is that the `y = 10` assignment may not be flushed, and hence the 2nd thread might see the default initial value (`0`) instead of `10`.

Possible solutions:

- Declare `y` as `final`.  Provided that the instance of `X` is not "published" before the constructor ends<sup>1</sup>, the JLS guarantees that other threads will see the correct value of `y`.
- Declare `y` as `volatile`.  The downside is that this adds a memory barrier before >>all<< reads to `y`; i.e. for every `getY()` call.
- Ensure that there is a *happens-before* chain between the completion of the `X` constructor in thread A and the call to `getY` in thread B.  This could be done by in various ways.  For example:

  - by passing the `X` instance from A to be via a `volatile` variable,
  - by passing it using synchronized method calls, or
  - by having thread `A` supply the shared `X` instance to `B` before it calls `start()` on the B thread.

---

<sup>1 - ... and you don't use nasty reflection, `Unsafe` or native code to break the `final`!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `volatile` if

1. variable is final
2. variable is used only by one thread
3. variable is accessed *only* in `synchronized` block.

Your code can be changed into case 1 if you make `y` final. Otherwise you should make it volatile.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If a variable is not declared volatile it can be cached in any thread.

However - if the variable is declared final, other considerations ensue.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Memory Model only provides initialisation safety for `final` fields of the object so, in theory, other threads could see a default value for a non-final field. For more complex objects they could see that the object was in a partially constructed state.

If, for example, your code was

```
public class X{
   List<Integer> y;

   public X(){
      y=Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4});
   }

   public List<Integer> getY(){
     return y;
   }
}
```

then you might find that your thread B saw a list with fewer than 4 elements in it.

If you want to access a field from multiple threads it *must* be `final` or `volatile` or accessed through a `synchronized` block.